# Otorgar bonos a empleados

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un problema que no logro analizarlo:

Tengo un array que contiene objetos con la siguiente característica:

```
[
  {
    vendedor_id: 1,
    salario: 2850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.91
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 2,
    salario: 3850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.90
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 5,
    salario: 2900,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.89
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 3,
    salario: 2000,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.75
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 4,
    salario: 1850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.67
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 7,
    salario: 2850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.51
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 6,
    salario: 3850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.48
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 8,
    salario: 1850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.32
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 9,
    salario: 1850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.25
  },
  {
    vendedor_id: 10,
    salario: 1850,
    procentaje_ventas: 0.16
  }
]
```

También tengo un monto de dinero destinado a ventas

```
let montoDestinado = 13000
```

Lo que intento es distribuir el `montoDestinado` el porcentajes `15%, 10%, 5% y 0%`y aumentarles el bono a su salario hasta que `montoDestinado` quede en `0` , obviamente los primeros vendedores tendrán bonos altos y siguientes bonos medios y bajos.

Alguna sugerencia de cómo podría distribuir ese dinero en base a los porcentajes mencionados?

> nota: La lista del JSON es más grande. stackoverflow no me deja
> publicar códigos extensos.

Comment: ¿Nos compartirías por favor lo que hayas intentado?

Comment: Como aclaración eso que muestras no es un json sino un objeto y no son exactamente lo mismo

Comment: donde ves el objeto?, en cualquier caso un array

Answer (score 4):

En tu lugar abordaría el problema de la siguiente manera:

1. Contaría cuantos Objetos tiene el arreglo (deberías ser igual a la cantidad de vendedores)

> ```
> const length = array.length
> ```

2. Haría una proporción matemática para calcular los porcentajes que mencionas y llevarlos al equivalente de 100%.

> Entonces: 15% + 10% + 5% + 0% = 30% <- Por lo tanto 30% será tu nuevo 100% y podrás obtener las ponderaciones equivalentes.

```
 - const prop15 = 15/30 = 0.5
 - const prop10 = 10/30 = 0.333
 - const prop5  = 5/30  = 0.1666
 - const prop0  = 0/30  = 0
```

3. Con las proporciones quedaría obtener el resultado de la fracción que relaciona el montoDestinado con la cantidad de categorías a evaluar (4 categorías porque son 4 porcentajes distintos)

> ```
>  let montoDestinado = 13000
>  const frac = 4 / montoDestinado
> ```

Donde 4 es la cantidad de % distintos a evaluar

4. Quedaría evaluar cuánto dinero se debe aumentar desde el **montoDestinado** a cada vendedor

> ```
>  - const eval15 = (mount/frac)*prop15
>  - const eval10 = (mount/frac)*prop10
>  - const eval5  = (mount/frac)*prop5
>  - const eval0  = (mount/frac)*prop0
> ```

5. El resultado de cada evaluación será el que tendrás que sumarle al **salario** de cada vendedor separándolos en 4 categorías (equivalentes a los 4 porcentajes distintos).

> Por ejemplo: si el arreglo tiene 20 vendedores, 20/4 = 5, por lo tanto
> los 5 primeros vendedores recibirán su `salario + eval15`, los 5
> siguientes vendedores recibirán su `salario + eval10` y así...

Nota: Importante es que identifiques y ordenes bien el arreglo acorde al criterio **procentaje_ventas** y que analices cómo abordar los casos donde la cantidad de vendedores no sea múltiplo de 4.